# BinarySearchTree Boat Charter record keeping

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, binary-search-tree

**This is for a Homework assignment**

For this assignment that I have to do, I have to create a recordkeeping log for a cruise liner for a month (represented by the numbers 1-31). There is 1 cruise a day that can hold up to 6 people. If the number of people trying to book on a certain day passes 6, then they will be added to a queue. The current passenger list is supposed to be held in a BinarySearchTree. Basically we are to read from a provided file information about a person object and insert them into a tree corresponding to the day they picked. (The file will give information in this order: (transactionCode day lastName firstName)) Where transaction code represents action taken (Add Passenger , Delete (Deletes passenger from tree and adds next passenger from queue), Print (Prints current BST and waiting list of day), Departure (Prints final list and queue of day).

The Question I am asking, is in regards to a method of creating a BST and a Queue that represents each and every day in a single method and adding to those BSTs. I am going blank in a method to accomplish this. I have already created a person object class, a BST Class, and a queue class. I can create an Add method in my passenger class, but how would I check to see if a tree already exists for a specific day, and add to that tree instead of creating a new one?

I am at a loss, if you need to see any classes, leave a comment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, here's what I think you should do.

- Have a array of nodes, each one representing a day.
- Make the nodes hold the letter `x` so has to shoe that they are empty.
- Have the root nodes pointing left and right until there are six nodes in each tree.
- The also make another array, again, each one representing a day.
- Fill each node with a `x` to show that it is not occupied.
- Now when you want to book a passenger, go to the day by going to it's index in the array of binary trees
- If the there's a `x` in it, that mean it's free, so store the passenger's name
- If there's another in it, check the left and right nodes until all six are checked
- If all six are filled then go to the Queue array of node, go to the index of the day, if it's a `x`, replace it with the passenger's name
- If it's not an `x` AND the root pointer is not NULL, say `root->next = new Node (passenger's name);`
- If the root pointer is a NULL, you'll have to go to the last person in the queue and then add on the new person.
- If a passenger is deleted for a day, go to the index in the queue, add the root node to the binary tree
- Then remove the name in the root node, swap it with the next in line...until there's no more in line.

I hope this helps. :)